Spring Boot - How to integrate custom LocaleResolver with Spring Security
I'm trying to change the application's locale from French to English. While everything works fine with Thymeleaf using my custom LocaleResolver, I am facing challenges with Spring Boot Security, as it seems to use its own messageSources() and not my custom LocaleResolver.
Here is my MessageResouce @Bean for my Spring Boot and I was expecting that Spring Security use the same LocaleResolver. But it's not.
@Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:lang/messages");
        messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(true);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return messageSource;
    }

And my LocaleResolver
@Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CustomLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CustomLocaleResolver(userService);
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(localeResolver.getLocale());
        return localeResolver;
    }

And here is my custom Resolver:
@Component
public class CustomLocaleResolver extends AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver {
    private Log logger;
    private UserService userService;
    private Locale locale;

    public CustomLocaleResolver(UserService userService) {
        logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {

        logger.debug("resolving for the best Locale choice");

        // 1. verify if user is authenticated and get locale from user
        locale = verifyUserForLocale();
        if(locale != null) {
            logger.debug("locale user lang: " + locale);
            return locale;
        }

        // 2. verify sessions attributes for locale
        if(request.getSession().getAttribute("locale") != null) {
            locale = Locale.forLanguageTag((String)request.getSession().getAttribute("locale"));
            if(locale != null) {
                logger.debug("locale session: " + locale);
                return locale;
            }
        }

        // 3. verify if cookie exist and get locale from cookie
        locale = verifyCookieForLocale(request);

        if(locale != null) {
            logger.debug("locale cookie: " + locale);
            return locale;
        }

        logger.debug("No user preference, session attribute or cookie found: Using default locale");
        // 3. verify if header exist and get locale from header
        return super.resolveLocale(request);
    }

    private Locale verifyHeaderForLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerLang = request.getHeader("Accept-Language");
        logger.debug("headerLang: " + headerLang);
        return Locale.getDefault();
    }

    private Locale verifyCookieForLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {

        if(request.getCookies() == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

        for(Cookie c : cookies) {
            //logger.info("cookie: " + c.getName() + " " + c.getValue());
            if(c.getName().equals("lang")) {
                logger.debug("cookie: " + c.getValue());
                return new Locale(c.getValue());
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private Locale verifyUserForLocale() {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if(authentication == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if(authentication.isAuthenticated() && authentication.getName() != "anonymousUser") {
            String username = authentication.getName();
            Locale locale = userService.getLocaleByUsername(username);

            if(locale == null) {
                logger.error("No locale found for user: " + username);
                return null;
            }
            logger.debug("locale user: " + locale);
            return locale;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public Locale getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }
}

